# SQL Server: Selecting DateTime and grouping by Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, date, group-by

This simple SQL problem is giving me a very hard time. Either because I'm seeing the problem the wrong way or because I'm not that familiar with SQL. Or both.

What I'm trying to do: I have a table with several columns and I only need two of them: the datetime when the entry was created and the id of the entry. Note that the hours/minutes/seconds part **is** important here.

However, I want to group my selection according to the DATE part only. Otherwise all groups will most likely have 1 element.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT MyDate as DateCr, COUNT(Id) as Occur
FROM MyTable tb WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY CAST(tb.MyDate as Date)
ORDER BY DateCr ASC
```

However I get the following error from it:

Column "MyTable.MyDate" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I don't do the cast in the GROUP BY, everything fine. If I cast MyDate to DATE in the SELECT and keep the CAST from GROUP BY, everything fine once more. Apparently it wants to keep the same DATE or DATETIME format in the GROUP BY as in the SELECT.

My approach can be completely wrong so I am **not** necessarily looking to fix the above query, but to find the proper way to do it.

LE: I get the above error on line 1.

**LE2: On a second look, my question indeed is not very explicit. You can ignore the above approach if it is completely wrong. Below is a sample scenario**

Let me tell you what I need: I want to retrieve (1) the DateTime when each entry was created. So if I have 20 entries, then I want to get 20 DateTimes. Then if I have multiple entries created on the same DAY, I want the number of those entries. For example, let's say I created 3 entries on Monday, 1 on Tuesday and 2 today. Then from my table I need the datetimes of these 6 entries + the number of entries which were created on each day (3 for 19/03/2012, 1 for 20/03/2012 and 2 for 21/03/2012).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're objecting to performing the `CONVERT` in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`. This seems like a perfectly logical way to do this:

```
SELECT 
  DateCr = CONVERT(DATE, MyDate), 
  Occur = COUNT(Id)
FROM dbo.MyTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, MyDate)
ORDER BY DateCr;
```

If you want to keep the time portion of `MyDate` in the `SELECT` list, why are you bothering to group? Or how do you expect the results to look? You'll have a row for every individual date/time value, where the grouping seems to indicate you want a row for each day. Maybe you could clarify what you want with some sample data and example desired results.

Also, why are you using `NOLOCK`? Are you willing to trade accuracy for a haphazard turbo button?

**EDIT** adding a version for the mixed requirements:

```
;WITH d(DateCr,d,Id) AS 
(
  SELECT MyDate, d = CONVERT(DATE, MyDate), Id
  FROM dbo.MyTable)
SELECT DateCr, Occur = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM d AS d2 WHERE d2.d = d.d)
FROM d
ORDER BY DateCr;
```

Comment: On a second look, my question indeed is not very explicit. Let me tell you what I need:

I want to retrieve (1) the DateTime when each entry was created. So if I have 20 entries, then I want to get 20 DateTimes. Then if I have multiple entries created on the same DAY, I want the number of those entries.

For example, let's say I created 3 entries on Monday, 1 on Tuesday and 2 today. Then from my table I need the datetimes of these 6 entries + the number of entries which were created on each day (3 for 19/03/2012, 1 for 20/03/2012 and 2 for 21/03/2012).

Comment: Aaron - out of interest, is it a performance issue converting in both the select and group by statments?

Comment: So you want the individual date/time values from Monday, and then a count that is *the exact same* on every row from Monday? Why not do this in two separate queries?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is an old post, I thought I would answer it. The solution below will work with SQL Server 2008 and above. It uses the over clause, so that the individual lines will be returned, but will also count the rows grouped by the date (without time).

```
SELECT MyDate as DateCr, 
      COUNT(Id) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(tb.MyDate as Date)) as Occur
FROM MyTable tb WITH(NOLOCK)
ORDER BY DateCr ASC
```

Darren White